# Determine the max values in one column based on another column

Tags: r, if-statement, max

I would like to determine the max the values in column `value1` based the values in column `value2`:

```
df <- 'inf value1 value2
       xx1   20    30
       xx2   15    40
       xx3   25    20'
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

My expected output would be like that:

```
out <- 'inf value1 value2
       xx1   20    30
       xx2   15    40
       xx3   20    20'
out <- read.table(text=out, header=T)
```

In the third row in the column `value2` now I have `20` instead `25`, because this is the value at `value2`column at the same row. I have a large dataset, I would appreciate any ideas to deal with that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you go from your input to your output?

Comment: you want to proceed per group in value2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also find the `min` value per row using `pmin`

```
with(df, pmin(value1, value2))
## [1] 20 15 20
```

---

**Some benchmarks**

```
set.seed(123)
test1 <- sample(1e3, 1e8, replace = TRUE)
test2 <- sample(1e3, 1e8, replace = TRUE)

### My solution
system.time(res1 <- pmin(test1, test2)) 
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.87    0.11    3.00 

### @Avinash
system.time(res2 <- ifelse(test1 < test2, test1, test2))
# user  system elapsed 
# 16.33    2.41   18.87 

### Contributed by @Colonel
system.time({temp <- test1 > test2 ; test1[temp] <- test2[temp]}) 
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.34    0.29    2.63 

identical(res1, res2)
# [1] TRUE
identical(res1, test1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: My comment was incomplete: I wanted to add that `df[df$value1>df$value2, 'value1']<-df[df$value1>df$value2, 'value2']`  should be equal or less time consuming than pmin.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel of that's a nice one, maybe worth posting.

Comment: I do not want to overload the topic for such a simple question, you can add it in your post and benchmark if you want.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel ok, added a benchmark with preallocation of the condition and it is turns out to be faster (a bit) indeed

Comment: Do we have a link to Colonel Dictionary somewhere?

Comment: it actually comes from Python official vocabulary on Pandas, transposition to R can be dubious :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use `ifelse`

```
df <- 'inf value1 value2
       xx1   20    30
       xx2   15    40
       xx3   25    20'
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
df$value1 <- ifelse(df$value2<df$value1,df$value2,df$value1)
df
#   inf value1 value2
# 1 xx1     20     30
# 2 xx2     15     40
# 3 xx3     20     20
```